# remove_if without the need of move and copy semantics

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, move-semantics, std

Here is what a typical vector remove-erase operation looks like :

```
auto toErase = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
   [val](obj_t const& obj) { return obj.myval == val; }
); // This actually moves objects around !

vec.erase(toErase, vec.end());
```

This works fine in the majority of cases, but I am faced with the case where `obj_t` type does not allow move or copy semantics. Objects are inserted with `vec.emplace_back()`, and I am looking for an alternative to `remove_if` that doesn't need either copy or move.

Does it already exist somewhere ? If not, how would it be built ?

Comment: Then perhaps a vector is not the correct container for you? Even when using `emplace_back` the vector might need to reallocate its data which means moving/copying of the objects.

Comment: note that `remove_if` does nothing else but moving/copying elements around. (and if you `erase` anywhere but at the end of the vector then again elements have to be moved/copied)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If object is non-movable/copyable how do you expect to rearrange objects in the vector? Vector is a contiguous container - so you cannot erase an element in the middle without shifting the ending.

To resolve the issue, either make the object movable/copyable, wrap it in `unique_ptr` (thus making it movable), or use one of `map/set/unordered_map` containers as those don't relocate objects unlike `std::vector`

Comment: Actually `std::list` might be a better alternative for `std::vector` than associative containers.

Comment: How would I remove-erase from a `std::list` without moving ?

Comment: I found ! used `std::list::remove_if( lambda )`

Comment: @rustyx I have little love for `std::list` as it lacks any forms of lookup. Very limited usage. But I suppose sometimes nothing else is required.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to remove from `std::vector` without copy or move support: how will you handle case, when you delete something from the middle? You can use for example `std::list<Class>` or `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Class>>` instead of `std::vector<Class>`.

Actually, if the main problem around `remove_if`: I recommend you use `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`

Comment: nitpick: your are mixing up things. "removing" in algorithm-speech does not actually delete anything. It only rearranges elements in the container.